# How to transfer large files between dockerized services?

Tags: file-upload, docker, rpc, microservices, grpc

I have an API/web app written in node.js -- the node app handles file upload, including audio files. The audio files need to undergo processing which is already built in python, and dependant on the python ecosystem and libraries available there.

Currently, I use gRPC to communicate between the 2 services - but the documentation on file streaming is very poor, and I have concerns about the performance implications. Specifically, if I have many active users uploading at once and I am streaming large, in-memory buffers I think I will run out of memory quickly.

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: You'd probably want a shared storage (which can be attached to your container's as a volume), where both the `node` container and the `python` container have access to. If both are running on a different node, you can consider using (e.g.) S3. There's various volume plugins that allow multi-host aware storage https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#/volume-plugins

Comment: You could also use a Network File System to store that data or put it in a shared data store (some Database systems allow for storing large binary data)

Comment: maybe you can use netcat, you `docker exec` into both, and you use the standard netcat commands, one listening, the other receiving, check also docker-netcat, see https://github.com/chilcano/docker-netcat